# Finding lineage of notebooks in azure databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, data-lineage

I am working on a project where we would be creating many notebooks in Azure databricks. In many cases there is a possibility to nesting notebook calls. We are looking for an approach to create automated lineage across notebooks. Any help or guidance here is appreciated.